# Compare 2D Arrays in Java and print differences

Tags: java, arrays, compare, logic

EDIT: closed because it seems that the code below works

I am currently facing the following problem:
I have two two-dimensional arrays, of which the second dimension always has the size 7 (max. index is therefore 6).
Now I need to compare these arrays.
I want to print out if there has been a field added or removed, at any index.

For example:

Array 1:

```
 0|1|2|3
0 |1|2|5
1 |4|4|6
(...)
6 |6|2|8
```

Array 2

```
 0|1|2|3|4
0 |1|1|2|5
1 |4|4|4|6
(...)
6 |6|7|2|8
```

As you can see, I have added a column to the second array.
Now I need to print out this column or add it to an array list.
The same has to happen when a column gets removed or changed.

How can I achieve that?

My code so far:

```
static List<String[]> differences;
static List<String[]> checkForDifferences(String[][] tableOld,String[][] tableNew) {
    differences = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    if(!Arrays.deepEquals(tableNew,tableOld)) {
        for(int hour = 0; hour < tableOld.length;hour++) {
            try {
                boolean removed = true;
                for(int hour2 = 0;hour2 < tableNew.length;hour2++)
                    if(Arrays.equals(tableOld[hour],tableNew[hour2]))
                        removed = false;
                    if(removed)
                        differences.add(new String[]{"-",tableOld[hour][0], tableOld[hour][1], tableOld[hour][2], tableOld[hour][3], tableOld[hour][4], tableOld[hour][5], tableOld[hour][6]});
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int hour = 0; hour < tableNew.length; hour++) {
            try {
                boolean added = true;
                for (int hour2 = 0; hour2 < tableOld.length; hour2++)
                    if (Arrays.equals(tableNew[hour], tableOld[hour2]))
                        added = false;
                if (added)
                    differences.add(new String[]{"+", tableNew[hour][0], tableNew[hour][1], tableNew[hour][2], tableNew[hour][3], tableNew[hour][4], tableNew[hour][5], tableNew[hour][6]});
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }

        return differences;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to check if sub-array array1[i] is present in array2 somewhere, if not it has been removed; if sub-array array2[i] is not present in array1 it has been added

Comment: please edit your post, and add your code to it, so we can try it out/see what is going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Please re-format your arrays in a more readable (more Java-like?) way (sorry, I can't really figure out anything without guessing). Then add at least two examples of what output you expect from a certain input.

Comment: Ive added my code so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, my code works. I was just using it wrong.